# Secha touch2: setting background image for form panel in tablet

Tags: sencha-touch-2, background-image

Hi I am new to sencha touch2, am facing problem while setting background image. I could not see full image on Tablet, the bottom part has been cutoff.
here is my view:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.LoginPage', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
    xtype: 'loginPage',

    config:{
        styleHtmlContent:'true',
        scrollable:'false',
        styleHtmlCls:'login-Cls',

        html: '<img class="logo" src="resources/images/login_Landscape_BG.png"/>'

    }

});
```

and do i need to add tablet in profiles folder as my app targets only for Tablet.
Can you please help me. Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of using `html`, you can try using `style` to set full background image:

```
style: 'background-image: url("resources/images/sesto-exterior.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%;'
```

Comment: Make sure your url to the image is correct, my code is just a sample.

Comment: FYi, this doesn't work w/ sencha touch 2.0.  The style needs to be put on the scrollview underneath where Sencha decides to put that style :-(

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had to follow this suggestion:
  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189231-Background-Image-in-form-Panel

and use this for my CSS (added the TxPanel cls to the form panel first):
.TxPanel .x-scroll-container {
    background: url('img/txbackground.png') repeat center;
}

But blechhh.  This is a pretty ugly hack :-P

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use Style config insteat of html config):

```
Ext.define('Test.view.LoginPage', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
    xtype: 'loginPage',

    config:{
        styleHtmlContent:'true',
        scrollable:'false',
        styleHtmlCls:'login-Cls',
        style: 'background-image:url(resources/images/login_Landscape_BG.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;'

    }

});
```